# Persisting x and y coordinates of a kendo diagram

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

How would kendo diagram shapes `x,y` coordinates be persisted. I've able to saved it's `x,y` coords to the database but still the diagram will rearranged the shapes to its default arrangement although it was already set as what I have in the datasource.

Does anyone here knows on what was happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say anything **certain** without seeing your source code but I guess that you have layout option in your diagram configuration which automaticaly rearrange positions of your shapes and connections.
for further information check this: 
[http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/diagram/layout](http://docs.telerik.com)

If you share your code, I can help more.

Answer (score 0):

Kendo diagram picks up the default 'tree down' layout and this overrides the x,y coordinates. To use no layout, you can use:

```
    $("#diagram").kendoDiagram({
            .......
            layout: false,
            .......
    });
```

You can refer to this example: https://jsfiddle.net/xhyyyn35/